# Walk-through for Portal advanced test chambers

Tags: portal

Where can I find a good walk-through of Portal's advanced test chambers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can find them all: http://www.portalwalkthroughs.com/

You can search for the one you want, or watch the advanced ones that are all in the homepage (scroll down a little)

Comment: This is a good one for video walkthroughs.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [GameFAQs walkthrough](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/934386-portal/faqs/50428) which contains the normal and advanced levels.